# Grouping of consecutive days for different employees

Tags: xml, xslt, grouping, xslt-2.0, xslt-grouping

I have a xml having different entries for different days for the same employee as below:

```
<wd:Report_Data
    <wd:Report_Entry>
        <wd:workerGroup>
            <wd:staffID>111</wd:staffID>
        </wd:workerGroup>
        <wd:workerType>Staff</wd:workerType>
        <wd:requestType>Absence Request</wd:requestType>
        <wd:date>2020-08-21-07:00</wd:date>
    </wd:Report_Entry>
    <wd:Report_Entry>
        <wd:workerGroup>
            <wd:staffID>111</wd:staffID>
        </wd:workerGroup>
        <wd:workerType>Staff</wd:workerType>
        <wd:requestType>Absence Request</wd:requestType>
        <wd:date>2020-08-22-07:00</wd:date>
    </wd:Report_Entry>
    <wd:Report_Entry>
        <wd:workerGroup>
            <wd:staffID>222</wd:staffID>
        </wd:workerGroup>
        <wd:workerType>Staff</wd:workerType>
        <wd:requestType>Absence Request</wd:requestType>
        <wd:date>2020-08-23-07:00</wd:date>
    </wd:Report_Entry>
    <wd:Report_Entry>
        <wd:workerGroup>
            <wd:staffID>333</wd:staffID>
        </wd:workerGroup>
        <wd:workerType>Staff</wd:workerType>
        <wd:requestType>Absence Request</wd:requestType>
        <wd:date>2020-08-15-07:00</wd:date>
    </wd:Report_Entry>
    <wd:Report_Entry>
        <wd:workerGroup>
            <wd:staffID>333</wd:staffID>
        </wd:workerGroup>
        <wd:workerType>Staff</wd:workerType>
        <wd:requestType>Absence Request</wd:requestType>
        <wd:date>2020-08-16-07:00</wd:date>
    </wd:Report_Entry>
    <wd:Report_Entry>
        <wd:workerGroup>
            <wd:staffID>333</wd:staffID>
        </wd:workerGroup>
        <wd:workerType>Staff</wd:workerType>
        <wd:requestType>Absence Request</wd:requestType>
        <wd:date>2020-08-29-07:00</wd:date>
    </wd:Report_Entry>
</wd:Report_Data>
```

I want an output which groups the consecutive days with a start date and an end date as below:

```
<wd:Report_Entry>
   <worker>
      <staffID>111</staffID>
      <start_date>2020-08-21-07:00</start_date>
      <end_date>2020-08-22-07:00</end_date>
   </worker>
   <worker>
      <staffID>222</staffID>
      <start_date>2020-08-23-07:00</start_date>
      <end_date>2020-08-23-07:00</end_date>
   </worker>
   <worker>
      <staffID>333</staffID>
      <start_date>2020-08-15-07:00</start_date>
      <end_date>2020-08-16-07:00</end_date>
   </worker>
   <worker>
      <staffID>333</staffID>
      <start_date>2020-08-29-07:00</start_date>
      <end_date>2020-08-29-07:00</end_date>
   </worker>
</wd:Report_Entry>
```

I have tried using **group-starting-with** but it is grouping irrespective of staffID.

```
<xsl:template match="/wd:Report_Data">
  
    <wd:Report_Entry>
              <xsl:for-each-group select="wd:Report_Entry" group-starting-with="*[not(xs:date(wd:date) = xs:date(preceding-sibling::*[1]/wd:date) + xs:dayTimeDuration('P1D'))] "> 
            <worker>
                <staffID>
                    <xsl:value-of select="wd:workerGroup/wd:staffID"/>
                </staffID>
                <start_date>
                    <xsl:value-of select="wd:date"/>
                </start_date>
                <end_date>
                    <xsl:value-of select="current-group()[last()]/wd:date"/>
                </end_date>
            </worker>
            </xsl:for-each-group>
        <!--   </xsl:for-each-group> --> 
    </wd:Report_Entry>
   
</xsl:template>
```

Getting output as below which is **WRONG**:

```
<wd:Report_Entry>
   <worker>
      <staffID>111</staffID>
      <start_date>2020-08-21-07:00</start_date>
      <end_date>2020-08-23-07:00</end_date>
   </worker>
</wd:Report_Entry>
```

Comment: It is not clear from that single example which variations the input can have. In your sample the two items for employee `111` are adjacent, then follows the item for the other employee. Also the time difference is exactly one day. Will the real input have the same simple structure of two adjacent elements with the one day time difference? Can there be more than two items for a single employee?

Comment: Yes @MartinHonnen. There will be 1 separate report entry for each day for each employee. e.g. If an employee requests for 5 days (say 20th - 24th) leave then we will have 5 different Report_Entry for each day - 20th, 21st, 22nd, 23rd, 24th. Then the same way we can have for different employees. The above code is a real input except the staffID

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems sufficient to use `group-by` on the staff id first and then sort the group on the date to then group by adjacent dates minus position() * 1 day:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="3.0"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xpath-default-namespace="http://example.com/wd"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    expand-text="yes">
    
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    
    <xsl:template match="Report_Data">
        <root>
            <xsl:for-each-group select="Report_Entry" group-by="workerGroup/staffID">
                <xsl:for-each-group select="sort(current-group(), (), function($e) { $e/date })" group-adjacent="xs:date(date) - position() * xs:dayTimeDuration('P1D')">
                    <worker>
                        <staffID>
                            <xsl:value-of select="workerGroup/staffID"/>
                        </staffID>
                        <start_date>
                            <xsl:value-of select="date[1]"/>
                        </start_date>
                        <end_date>
                            <xsl:value-of select="current-group()[last()]/date"/>
                        </end_date>
                    </worker>
                </xsl:for-each-group>
            </xsl:for-each-group>
        </root>
    </xsl:template>
    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

For an XSLT 2 processor you might need to implement the sorting in a user-defined function based on `xsl:perform-sort`:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="3.0"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:mf="http://example.com/mf"
    xpath-default-namespace="http://example.com/wd"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    expand-text="yes">
    
    <xsl:function name="mf:sort-by-date" as="element(Report_Entry)*">
        <xsl:param name="entries" as="element(Report_Entry)*"/>
        <xsl:perform-sort select="$entries">
            <xsl:sort select="date"/>
        </xsl:perform-sort>
    </xsl:function>
    
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    
    <xsl:template match="Report_Data">
        <root>
            <xsl:for-each-group select="Report_Entry" group-by="workerGroup/staffID">
                <xsl:for-each-group select="mf:sort-by-date(current-group())" group-adjacent="xs:date(date) - position() * xs:dayTimeDuration('P1D')">
                    <worker>
                        <staffID>
                            <xsl:value-of select="workerGroup/staffID"/>
                        </staffID>
                        <start_date>
                            <xsl:value-of select="date[1]"/>
                        </start_date>
                        <end_date>
                            <xsl:value-of select="current-group()[last()]/date"/>
                        </end_date>
                    </worker>
                </xsl:for-each-group>
            </xsl:for-each-group>
        </root>
    </xsl:template>
    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Of course the sorting is only necessary if the input is not sorted by staff id and date, otherwise the presented grouping should suffice.

Comment: Thanks @martin but this way it will group non-consecutive days as well. If an employee applies for leave from 20th to 22nd and again 25th to 28th then I should get 2 groups(Group 1: 20-22; Group2: 25-28). Which is why I am trying with `<xsl:for-each-group select="wd:Report_Entry" group-starting-with="*[not(xs:date(wd:date) = xs:date(preceding-sibling::*[1]/wd:date) + xs:dayTimeDuration('P1D'))] ">`Your code will give only 1 group with start date 20th and end date 28th

Comment: The grouping should happen only if the staff IDs are same and the dates are consecutive

Comment: @AdityaGG, can you edit your question and show us input and output samples for the cases where an employee will produce more than one group. I still don't see whether groups are formed for all items being a day apart or for any gap.

Comment: @AdityaGG, see whether the edit is closer to what you want.

Comment: I have edited my input and expected output above (added a scenario for another employee 333). There should be 2 groups for 333 - from 15th to 16th because they are consecutive days and another group for 29th.
The first scenario was for 2 employees - 111 (21st and 22nd) and 222 (23rd). Here all the dates are consecutive but since the staffID is different, I want 2 groups - one each for 111 (start date 21st; end date 22nd) and 222  (start date 23rd; end date 23rd)

Comment: Please help writing the code in XSLT 2.0  I am not much familiar with XSLT 3.0

Comment: @AdityaGG, based on your edited samples I have rewritten the answer, see whether it solves the problem.